# Traefik - redirect and trailing slash

Tags: traefik

I have one URL managed by two containers, eg:

- http://www.example.com -> container1
- http://www.example.com/foo -> container2

I need add trailing slash after `foo` and I've write this in compose file (and work):

```
- "traefik.01.frontend.redirect.regex=^(.*)/foo$$"
- "traefik.01.frontend.redirect.replacement=$$1/foo/"
- "traefik.01.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/foo;ReplacePathRegex: ^/foo/(.*) /$$1"
```

Now, into container2, I have other folder `admin` to access into backend configuration of site, and i need add trailing slash also in this path, eg.

- http://www.example.com/foo/admin --> doesn't work
- http://www.example.com/foo/admin/ --> work

I've try to add same rule for `admin` folder

```
- "traefik.01.frontend.redirect.regex=^(.*)/foo$$"
- "traefik.01.frontend.redirect.replacement=$$1/foo/"
- "traefik.01.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/foo;ReplacePathRegex: ^/foo/(.*) /$$1"
- "traefik.02.frontend.redirect.regex=^(.*)/foo/admin$$"
- "traefik.02.frontend.redirect.replacement=$$1/foo/admin/"
- "traefik.02.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/foo/admin;ReplacePathRegex: ^/foo/admin/(.*) /$$1"
```

Now, if I type `http://www.example.com/foo/admin` redirect correctly to `http://www.example.com/foo/admin/` but i see the content of `http://www.example.com/foo/` (home page of container2), it seems that the rule `"traefik.01.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/foo;ReplacePathRegex: ^/foo/(.*) /$$1"` takes precedence, is there a way?